# Splitting string (from a random line) into two variables

Tags: python

I am trying to split a string that is given randomly into two variables. Tried using '.split' but I can't make it work. If possible, giving me the simplest yet working method is very much appreciated as I'm still somewhat a novice in python. This is what I'm working with at the moment...

```
file = open("CapitalCities.txt","r")
file_contents = file.read()

import random
def generateQuiz():
    with open ("CapitalCities.txt") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        print(random.choice(lines))

generateQuiz()
```

...and this is some of the content of the text file I'm using:

> ```
> Albania-Tirana 
> Andorra-Andorra la Vella 
> Armenia-Yerevan
> Austria-Vienna 
> Azerbaijan-Baku 
> Belarus-Minsk 
> Belgium-Brussels 
> Bosnia    and    Herzegovina-Sarajevo       
> Bulgaria-Sofia
> ```

(Edit: Forgot to mention. The split has to trigger with '-'. I am clueless to how I remove the '-' after doing the split)

Comment: What happened when you tried `.split('-')`?

Comment: What is the purpose of the first two lines `file = open(); file_contents = file.read()`? You never use them again. Are you trying to split say `Albania-Tirana` into two variables `x = Albania; y = Tirana`?

Comment: What exactly is the problem and the expected output here?

Comment: @DanielH It gave me 'AttributeError'. I'm sure it's the way I wrote it that gave me the error

Comment: @pstatix Removed them. Did not come to mind that they had no purpose and yes, they split in that way

Comment: What did you try `split`ting? Can you please show the broken code and the full error message? An `AttributeError` implies that whatever you put that on wasn't a string; did you try saying `lines.split`? Since `lines` is a list of strings, not a single string, that won't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll obviously need to tailor this to whatever your end goal is, but for now it shows you how to build a list of sublists that represent each of the string pairs separated by a `-` and allows you to randomly pick one of the sublists and store them in variables `x` and `y`.

```
import random
def generateQuiz():
    with open("CapitalCities.txt") as f:
        # create a list of sublists; [['Albania', 'Tirana'], ['Andorra', 'Andorra la Vella'], ...,]
        # strip() removes '\n', split('-') returns the sublists
        pairs = [line.strip().split('-') for line in f] 
        # pick a random sublist
        # the '=' will try to unpack the two into x and y
        x, y = random.choice(pairs) 
        print(x, y)

generateQuiz()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this will help:

```
import random
def generateQuiz():
    with open ("CapitalCities.txt") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        words = random.choice(lines).split('-')
        state = words[0]
        capital = words[1]
        print(state, capital)
generateQuiz()
```

Answer (score -1):

If each of your rows is of the form `'string1-string2'`, then you should use `.split('-')`.

```
In [0]: 'string1-string2'.split('-')
Out[0]: ['string1', 'string2']
```